# Accessing secured static files when using x-auth-token

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-security, http-headers, spring-session

I'm using an `x-auth-token` generated by spring session to maintain communication, this is fine for ajax requests.I have a problem though, I have files that are *not* currently being fetched by ajax.

These files are   user uploaded content, pdfs, html with css and fonts, basically things the browser can render, so making an ajax force download button isn't an option (though maybe there's a way to do this to view them that I'm not thinking of). Currently they are just being requested by a browser GET via `<a href` links, so no header is included.

I am using AngularJS. What's the best way to address this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is a couple months old, but I ran into this problem with AngularJS when I first moved to using Spring Session also.  It's a little hacky, but it essentially uses AngularJS's HTTP to retrieve the document and save it in a BLOB in the Browser.  Then, a hidden `<a>` tag is created with a link to the BLOB and the link is clicked programmatically.  I have an AngularJS service called 'saveBlob' that handles this:

```
app.service('saveBlob', ['$http', function ($http) {
return {
    download: function(url, fileName) {
        $http.get(url, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' }).then(function(response) {
            var blob = new Blob(
                    [ response.data ], 
                    { type: response.headers('Content-Type') }
                );
            var objUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            var a = document.createElement("a");
            document.body.appendChild(a);
            a.style = "display: none";
            a.href = objUrl;
            if (fileName) {
                a.download = fileName;
            }
            else {
                var regex = /filename[^;=\n]*=((['"]).*?\2|[^;\n]*)/g;
                var match = regex.exec(response.headers('Content-Disposition'));
                var fn = match[1];
                a.download = fn.substring(1, fn.length - 1);
            }
            a.click();
            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
        });
    }
}
}]);
```

The 'saveBlob' service is then called by a directive called 'httpHref':

```
app.directive('httpHref', ['$http', 'saveBlob', function ($http, saveBlob) {
return {
    link: function ($scope, elem, attrs) {
        function revokeObjectURL() {
            if ($scope.objectURL) {
                URL.revokeObjectURL($scope.objectURL);
            }
        }

        $scope.$watch('objectURL', function (objectURL) {
            elem.attr('href', objectURL);
        });

        $scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
            revokeObjectURL();
        });

        attrs.$observe('httpHref', function (url) {
            elem[0].onclick = function() {
                saveBlob.download(url);
            };
        });
    }
};
}]);
```

I adapted this code from [This GitHub Repository](https://github.com/dougmoscrop/angular-img-http-src/blob/master/index.js) (which is licensed under the MIT License), so thank you to the contributors of that project for helping me with this!

Comment: might be useful to someone, I ended up migrating to Aurelia, but I'm sure I could find a way to convert this to aurelia/fetch api